# A beat game where you can create custom levels

Tags: music, game

Does anyone know a beat game where you can create custom levels with mp3 files? Thank you. (Windows and/or android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For desktop OSs like Windows both [Audiosurf](https://store.steampowered.com/app/12900/AudioSurf/) and [Audiosurf 2](https://store.steampowered.com/app/235800/Audiosurf_2/) feature music based gameplay akin to beat games with any custom track.

There are several gaming modes, but most center around navigating on a three lane track while picking up colored blocks and avoiding black ones. Different modes add different nuances to the base loop.

Both games feature rhythm based mechanics similar to beat games and "levels" are automatically generated from any custom local track you have saved in your hard drive. Most common audio file formats including but not limited to Mp3, Mp4, Flac, Wav are supported.

There are online worldwide and local scoreboards per music, per mode.